# How and if test syntactic (bad request) validation with Pact?

Tags: java, testing, tdd, microservices, pact

I'm starting to use Pact (on Java) for Contract Tests.

I've read [Contract Tests vs Functional Tests](https://docs.pact.io/best-practices/consumer/contract-tests-vs-functional-tests) on Pact best practices but I'm a little confused.

**Example**: a simple REST endpoint that creates a resource (POST), returning a 201 Created on success and 400 Bad Request for syntactic validation errors.
The request body is something like:

```
{
    "firstname" : "Foo",
    "lastname" : "Bar"
}
```

Both `firstname` and `lastname` must not be blank. So far as I understand I could write 3 scenarios here, in which the provider should return 400 Bad Request:

1. `firstname` is **blank**, `lastname` is not blank
2. `firstname` is not blank, `lastname` is **blank**
3. `firstname` and `lastname` are **both** blank

The thing is that the mock server returns a 500 Internal Server Error if only the "happy path pact" is defined, and if I want to make it return 400 Bad Request I have to write all possible pacts. Moreover, if I add another fields with the same validation rule the number of pacts explodes.

- First of all, should I test that scenarios on my consumer?
- If yes, do exists any smart way to implement it with Pact DSL?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I’m establishing a contract for a `POST`, I care about the server accepting a valid input and the way the server responds (usually `400`) to a bad input. There’s no need to have a contract for all the possible ways an input might be invalid, mainly because this can happen for an uncountable number of reasons.

So, I, from a consumer perspective, typically have only one interaction for invalid inputs, unless I’m facing a very particular situation where the server might respond differently depending on the reason of the failure, and I care about the different responses.

For your specific situation, write a contract for just one of the three mentioned scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

The core message of the Functional vs Contract discussion in your case is this: those permutations of unhappy paths belong in your Provider code, because that is where the logic is.

As @fabricio-lemos puts it, you just need to encapsulate a single example of a 400 bad request to prove that your code can handle that case.

As for the 500 error, that is possibly because you are not setting up a single expected interaction (via the Pact DSL) per test. If you hit the Pact mock server before the expected interaction has been registered, you get the 500.

In pseudo-code your test structure might look like

```
Describe "User API"
  BeforeAll
     setup Pact mock server
  AfterEach
     verify and clear interactions 
  With valid request
     setup 201 interaction
     run tests
  With invalid request
     setup 400 interaction
     run tests
```